# Linear systems over $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I am studying from the book and there is an example given which I can't figure out.

Solving a matrix in $\Bbb Z_p$ where p is a prime number has many respects like $\Bbb R$; like adding, substracting, multiplying and dividing.

If you have the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1$ in $\Bbb Z_2$ there are 4 solutions given.

The solutions which are given are:

$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

As you see gives the last solution:

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1$

$1 + 1 + 1 = 1$

The first three seems logic to me, but I am not sure why the forth solution is legit.

Comment: In a field of characteristic $2$ as $\mathbb{Z}_2$ You have $1+1=0$ and thus $1+1+1=0+1=1$

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb{Z}_2$, $1+1=0$ and therefore $1+1+1=0+1=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reaction. And what you are suggesting is veryfied by [by this explanation?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer#Construction) Until now I am used to calculate in $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb R$, so this concept is quite new for me.